# Evaluating a checkbox in a cloned table row using javascript

Tags: javascript

The following .js clones a selected table row to another table when the target row's button is pressed.  One of the cells in the row has a checkbox with id="vrbl."  As you can see from my code below I want to add a textarea to the cloned row that is disabled if the checkbox is not checked.  I know I am not identifying and evaluating the checkbox's "checked" status appropriately but I am struggling to get the code to work here.  Appreciate any help!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var items = [];
$("button").click(function() {
    var newTr = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
    var newButtonHTML = "<input type='button' value='Delete' style='font-size: 10px;' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/>";
    if ($(newTr).children("#vrbl").prop('checked')) {
        var newtextarea = "<textarea></textarea>"
    }
    else {
        var newtextarea = "<textarea disabled></textarea>"
    };
    $(newTr).children("td:nth-child(6)").html("").html(newtextarea);
    items.push(newTr);
    $(newTr).children("td:nth-child(7)").html("").html(newButtonHTML);
    items.push(newTr);
    newTr.appendTo($("#myTable2"));
});
```

})

Comment: remember the id should be unique when you clone element and append it back there will be 2 element with same id and that 's not a valid ID..

Comment: Good catch on the id.  I think my bigger problem is the code `$(newTr).children("#vrbl").prop('checked')` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.getElementById("vrbl"+this.id).checked==true) {
```

Above worked!  Appreciate the tip.